# Can I place HS22 and LS22 blades in the same BladeCenter?

Tags: blade-server, bladecenter

Is it possible to place HS22 and LS22 blades in the same IBM BladeCenter without compatability issues?

Comment: One needs to know your chassis type to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can mix any combination of blades in the same BladeCenter chassis *provided* the blades themselves are supported in that chassis.

The [table here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/SG247523/wwhelp/wwhimpl/api.htm?href=1-1-1.htm) lists the compatibility table between blades and chassis.

(huh, actually the LS22 is no longer listed. You can find it's compatibility list [here](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/blade/7901.html).)

Answer (score 0):

On IBM's webpage there is a "bladecenter redbook" this correctly answers your question.

This is one of that:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/Redbooks.nsf/RedbookAbstracts/sg247523.html

Comment: It's considered bad form on this site to simply provide a reference without actually providing the answer. By all means, please do provide the reference - but also please answer the question.